# How to update a specific row(s) in p:panelgrid?

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

**Question:** How may I update several single rows of a `p:panelGrid`?

I am currently creating a complex table with `p:panelGrid` and custom facelet tags for templating. Some events triggered in several cells requires an update of other parts of the table. It would be very handy to be able to update a complete row at once. So far I am only able to update content inside single Cells.

**My Custom tag:**

```
<p:row id=#{rowid}>
   <p:column>
       <some:inputComponent>
           <p:ajax update=#{toupdate} />
       </some:inputComponent> 
   </p:column>
</p:row>
```

**Usage in the PanelGrid:**

```
<p:panelGrid>
  <my:row value=#{foo} rowid="one" />
  <my:row value=#{bar} rowid="two" toupdate="one"/>
</p:panelGrid>
```

On change of some Component (like `p:spinner` in my case) in the second row and after executation of some action listener, I want to update the complete first row. But if I am going to do it like that it totally destroys the outcome:

Before the update:

[image]

After the update:

[image]

As one can see in the generated HTML, it does not rerender all the `tr` and `td` tags, so everything appears in the first "column" of the table:

[image]

Work around:

- wrap the content of each Cell in some container and update those containers individually (This works fine, but it is quite ugly as I have to know the implemention details of each row in the other one)

---

**UPDATE:**

The comments so far have been very helpful. I am now able to to update a single row without the need about having too much knowledge about its internal structure. I replaced the ID of the row by a styleClass attribute and added a styleClass attribute to the input Component as well.

```
<p:row styleClass=#{rowid}>
   <p:column>
       <some:inputComponent styleClass="foo">
           <p:ajax update="@(.#{toupdate} .mysuffix)" />
       </some:inputComponent> 
   </p:column>
</p:row>
```

As I said, this works fine if `toupdate` caintains only one single "ID", but I also want to be able to update more than one row in that way. I would like to use my component like this:

```
<p:panelGrid>
   <my:row value=#{foo} rowid="one" />
   <my:row value=#{bar} rowid="two" />
   <my:row value=#{fobar} rowid="three" toupdate="one two"/>
</p:panelGrid>
```

(As this is more related to jQuery now, I added the jQuery tag on this question as well.)

---

**SOLUTION:**

The final approach looks like that:

```
<c:set var="u" value="#{empty parentids ? parentids :
       of:concat(fn:join(fn:split(toupdate,' '), ' .mysuffix,'),' .mysuffix')}" />
// ....
update="@({u})"
```

It is quite close to Kukeltjes suggestion, the only problem was that the join does not append the styleclass after the last value. Also it caused problems when no IDs where passed.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1867

Comment: @JasperdeVries: Yes, it is part of the solution, but since you cannot 'update' a row since it has no 'renderer' you need to prefix all components with the id from the 'custom tag' and use that in the selector you refer to.

Comment: @Kukeltje Jasper de Vries .. thank you both, I am one step further to the solution now. I updated my question (or should I rather create a new question for the jquery related part?)

Comment: You should be able to use multiple selectors separated by a comma `update="@(.one .mysuffix, .two .mysuffix)"`

Comment: does `@((#{toupdate}) .mysuffix)` work and then using `toupdate=".one, .two")

Comment: @JasperdeVries: yes, but find an EL way of first splitting and then joining that works. I've just been looking quickly but only found things that requires jstl and I'm not sure that works.

Comment: @Kukeltje maybe send BalusC a feature request to add `joinFormatted` to http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Converters ;-)

Comment: :-)  Maybe `@(#{fn:join(fn:split(toupdate, ' '), ' .mysuffix, ')})` works, but then you still need to define `toupdate=".one .two"`

Comment: I tried it with a seperating comma and without, in both cases I get a JS error:  *Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:* `(.one, .two) .mysuffix` Are you able to spot what's wrong here? in the rendered HTML inside th onchange attribute, it looks like that: `@((.one, .two) .mysuffix)`

Comment: I don't think you can group jQuery selectors like that and that you have to use full expressions separated using a comma.

Comment: I missed some quotes and brackets... What I'd wanted to have is `@((".one, .two").(".mysuffix"))`. Not sure if it works, just a suggestion

Comment: If you are interested in it, you'll find my solution in the end of the question. Thank you very much for your help! :)